# Entity Framework data service request headers for mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wpf, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

We have an Entity framework web service, that needs authentication to access. This authentication needs to happen every time a request is sent.

The system im editing has it working perfectly for a WPF application by overriding the OnSendingRequest event of the entity container from the mainWindow.xaml.cs file. then adding the authorization to the header. And i found a resource that tells me to do something similar, but i dont know how this works in a  ASP.NET MVC project, since the resource seems to only give an example of how to do it for a single request, in WPF. [How to: Set Headers in the Client Request (WCF Data Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/wcf/how-to-set-headers-in-the-client-request-wcf-data-services)

I need to make this same authentication header for the connection of the mvc project, for every request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase someone else finds this useful, i solved the problem by accident.

I made a static class, and a static method, that can be called from any page in the project. with this code:

```
var serviceUri = new Uri(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataServiceUri"]);
myService result = new myService(serviceUri);

result.SendingRequest += new EventHandler<SendingRequestEventArgs>((s, e) =>
{
    string authenticationString = applicationName + " " + applicationId;
    e.RequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authenticationString);
});

return result;
```

This both creates and returns the instance of the service, to use in the calling method, and also automatically creates the Authorization and executes it.

This hasto be done on each of the controllers that communicates with the service.
Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try message interceptor to insert authentication headers.

```
 public class ClientMessageLogger : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        MessageHeader header1 = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Testreply", "http://Test", "Test");
    request.Headers.Add(header1);
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        MessageHeader header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("UserAgent", "http://User", "User1");
    reply.Headers.Add(header);
    return null;

    }
}
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface)]
public class CustomBehavior : Attribute, IContractBehavior
{
    public Type TargetContract => typeof(ServiceReference1.ICalculator);
    public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(new ClientMessageLogger());
    }
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

In the BeforeSendRequest method, you can insert a header, to apply this message interceptor, you need to add [CustomBehavior] in the client's service reference.

Like this: [image]